# Prove / Disprove function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ be arbitrary functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{+}$. Prove or disprove the following: $$f(n)+g(n) = \Theta(\min\left \{ f(n), g(n) \right \})$$
Please help me prove (or disprove) this function as I am unsure how to resolve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f(n) = 1$ and $g(n) = n$. Then clearly $f(n) + g(n) = 1 + n = \Theta(n)$. But since $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $min{\{f(n), g(n)}\} = 1 = \Theta(1)$ and thus, since this is a counterexample, the statement is false.

Answer (score 1):

Irvan wrote a fine solution, but the problem seems to be that you don't know how to handle this kind of problem. Try putting the statement into a sentence that is not 100% mathematically correct, but good enough to start your intuition. Like

```
"f + g is very roughly not larger than the smaller of f and g".
```

Does that sound right to you? What if one is really, really small and the other is really, really big? Their sum will be really, really big while the smaller one will be really, really small. Doesn't sound right to me.

And of course that's just what Irvan did with his example: f (n) = 1 is small, g (n) = n is big.

Now to see if you learned something, try the exact same problem, with with "max" instead of "min".

Comment: This gives a much clearer understanding to the problem! I appreciate your input on this